# Script fails when run over inline ssh but not locally or over full ssh session

Tags: ssh, remote, openssh, kubuntu

I have a script on a server that pulls from a remote git repo then compiles the code with make and presents a compiled file to download.  When I run locally on the machine or through a regular ssh session everything goes fine.  However, when I run inline with ssh.

```
ssh usr@server /script/location.sh arg1
```

This then fails.  Looking at the build log it is a command not being found and the build fails. ([`qcc`](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_utilities%2Fq%2Fqcc.html) specifically) The script then continues on and some other errors occur given that necessary files aren't completed and present.

From doing some research it sounded like it could be an environment difference when running like this.  (Would this be called running through `sshd`?) I tried adding a `PermitUserEnvironment yes` to the end of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restarting but this didn't seem to work.

The server is on kubuntu 14.04 
SSH is OpenSSH 6.6.1
This system is from a vendor, so I'm not sure how things were set up originally

Comment: What does `type qcc` say when you are **logged in** on the server? This sounds like a confusion over where to put setup instructions, `~/.bash_login` vs `~/.bashrc`

Comment: @icarus Logged in it gives '/opt/qnx660/host/linux/x86/usr/bin/qcc' while using an inline ssh it gives 'bash: line 0: type: qcc not found'.  neither '~/.bash_login' or '~/.bashrc' exist as well.

Comment: OK, so there is probably a file in /etc/profile.d which adds /opt/qnx660/host/linux/x86/usr/bin to the PATH variable. If you can edit /script/location.sh then you can add "source /etc/profile.d/QNXfilename" near the beginning. If you can't edit the file then invoke the command as `ssh usr@server bash -c 'source /etc/profile.d/QNXfilename && /script/location.sh arg1'

Comment: @icarus The only file in '/etc/profile.d/' is a 'bash_completion.sh' which doesn't have any mention of that kind of thing.  Am I going about this wrong?  Would there perhaps be a way that I could have a local user execute the script?  I don't care about seeing output or anything when I send the command so if the local user would be able to listen for something and then execute on it's own, then that would be fine.

Comment: Is there any reference to /opt/qnx660 in /etc/profile or /etc/bash.bashrc?